# Jquery DataTables virtual scrolling horizontally

Tags: datatables, scroller

I use [Scroller](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/) plug-in to display a large number of rows. However, it does not seem to support **virtual** scrolling horizontally for columns, or I have not found the solution yet. Does anyone has any suggestions in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no support in the Scroller extension for virtual horizontal scrolling. I am not aware of any such feature anywhere in DataTables. When a row is displayed, it is always the full row, never part of a row. You can certainly use horizontal scrolling, and fixed columns - but those are not _virtual_ horizontal features.

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @andrewjames Thanks for the comment. I have a large set of data as resource planning schedule which shows a list of people as rows and dates as column. The date range can be very long between 6 months to 1 year or more. It would be very bad performance to show such large data, especially for a long period.

Comment: Do you know for a fact that wide rows will perform poorly? If you are using lazy loading (scroller, or serverSide), I expect you would need to have extremely wide rows for you to actually have a performance issue, because you will only be handling a very small number of these very wide rows.

Comment: Yes, I do. That's why I'm looking for a solution that renders the wide rows virtually when scrolling horizontally as the same way that Scroller supports virtual scrolling vertically.